¿Cómo abro una imagen desde la base de datos en tkinter?
estoy intentando abrir una imagen que tengo guardado en una base de datos sqlite3 en tipo BLOB, pero al ser un archivo en binario no se como abrirlo.
    #estas son las librerias que he usado
    import tkinter as tk
    import sqlite3, io

    #este es el bloque de codigo con el que quiero abrir la imagen
    #brawler es la fila de la tabla de la base de datos, brawler[5] es la imagen guardada en BLOB
    img = io.BytesIO(brawler[5])
    pic = tk.PhotoImage(file=img)
    self.foto1= pic

    self.label_f1 = tk.Label(self.f1,image=self.foto1).pack()
    
    
    


Si el formato de la imagen es uno de los admitidos por tkinter.PhotoImage (PGM, PPM, GIF o PNG) puedes cargar la imagen usando directamente el objeto bytes que recibes de la consulta a través del argumento data. Dependiendo del formato de la imagen, puede que tengas que indicarlo de forma explícita a través del argumento format (por ejemplo formatos que no incluyen esa información en sus headers).
Un ejemplo reproducible:
from urllib.request import urlopen
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk


imagen = urlopen("https://www.python.org/static/community_logos/python-powered-w-200x80.png").read()
with sqlite3.connect(":memory:") as con:
    con.execute("CREATE TABLE test(imagenes blob)")
    con.execute("INSERT INTO test (imagenes) VALUES (?)", (imagen,))
    
    data = con.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
    img_bin = next(data)[0]

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
foto = tk.PhotoImage(data=img_bin)
tk.Label(root, image=foto).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
root.mainloop()


Nótese que el argumento data también acepta en ciertos casos (por ejemplo para GIF) una entrada con la imagen codificada en Base64.

Si el formato no es uno de los soportado por tkinter, o se convierte previamente a uno antes de insertar en la BD, o se puede usar PIL (pillow) como muestra la respuesta de Rodrigo Llares, que admite mucha más variedad de formatos.

Muchas gracias, soy nuevo en esto y no conocí el data.

@AZG la verdad es que la documentación de tkinter no es la mejor (en parte porque en realidad es solo un wrapper en torno a tcl/tk), desde luego no está a a la altura de la documentación del resto de la STDLib de Python. Hay muchos tutoriales online y StackOverflow también te puede resolver muchas dudas, pero muchas veces si quieres profundizar  y explotar al máximo el framework tienes que recurrir a la documentación de tcl/tk o indagar en el código fuente/docstrings de tkinter.

Puedes usar Pillow para obtener la imagen y luego emplear esa imagen en Tkinter.
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(brawler[5]))
tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)


Gracias, no sabía como hacerlo

@AZG de nada, para eso estamos
